# Remove gap between rows in GWT Grid

Tags: java, css, gwt

I've got a GWT Grid filled with Image widgets:

```
private Grid puzzleTable = new Grid(4, 2);
[...]
for ( y = 0; y < 3; ++y ) {
  for ( x=0; x < 2; ++x ) {
    Image img = new Image( DEFAULT_IMAGE_DIR+"/portrait"+"_"+y+"_"+x+".png" );
    puzzleTable.setWidget( y, x, img );
  }
}
```

Then I want to remove all the spacing/padding of the table cells:

```
puzzleTable.setCellPadding(0);
puzzleTable.setCellSpacing(0);
```

However, there remains a gap between the rows. The gap seems to be some spacing for the bottom of the cell. I already tried to apply different CSS settings to the table, rows and cells but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Comment: It's most likely CSS, if you can post a short snippet (preferrably using jsfiddle) that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `new Image(..)` creates an `img` element in the HTML:

Add this CSS:

```
td img {
    display: block
}
```

For an explanation, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images%2c_Tables%2c_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Comment: Actually, I've chosen GWT so I don't need to deal with all the web browser specific quirks. But it seems I don't even get around it with GWT. Your answer solved my problem. Thanks!